# Processing paths in m3u file

Tags: shell, awk

I'm trying to process an m3u playlist file structured as is:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTING:193,Song name
/path/to/the/song.mp3
#EXTING:201,Another song
/somewhere/in/a directory/song2.mp3
```

The aim is, for every line containing a path, remove the path and keep only filename and extension. For example, the file above would become:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTING:193,Song name
song.mp3
#EXTING:201,Another song
song2.mp3
```

I tried with awk several variations, the closest I could get was this one:

```
awk '{if ((NR % 2 == 1) && (NR != 1)){print "$(basename $0)"}else{print}}' playlist.m3u
```

The if/else structure is ok, only the "print basename" thing doesn't work, and I have to admit that shell is not my strong suit ;)

Can someone help?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: seems, he wants the # line also..  awk -F/ '!/^#/{$0=$NF}1' playlist.m3u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F/ '!/^#/{$0=$NF}1' playlist.m3u
```